# Send a POST when the user hits the bottom?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

There are loads of questions that have this same problem, but all the ones I've found will only tell you how the actual javascript works, not the routing for this kind of thing.

So I'm a bit lost at the moment trying to implement the html and routing side of an infinite scroll system using only Node.js, Express, and Mongodb.

I know how to do the checks for when the user hits the bottom, and I know you need to have some kind of listener in an app.post route that will tell the database to append the data. But I don't know what is doing the 'posting', and how should I route it.

Is it simply an onClick listener that is watching for a "submit" value to be true? And when the user hits the bottom, it becomes true, Express gets the POST, loads ten more entries.

I literally don't understand the actual concept of waiting for an event value in the routing file, I thought the whole point of separating the front and back end meant you could not wait for a value to be "true" in javascript and return that.

This is a pretty general question I think, and my code is probably not needed.

So if anyone could give a decently broad explanation of how I should be looking at the whole event listening thing and the routing for it, that would help a lot. Currently seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "what is doing the 'posting'"

When a **Form** gets **submitted**, it's that which does the 'POSTing'. A "submit" is an action, like a function call, not simply a boolean value being watched for true or false.

```
<form method="POST" action="/url">
    <input name="name" value="value">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here when the button will be clicked, a POST request will be fired off to the server.

```
app.post('/url', function(res, res, next){
    req.body //=> {name: 'value'}
});
```

---

> Is it simply an onClick listener that is watching for a "submit" value to be true?

An `onClick` event is an event. A listener is a function, attached to it, that is fired when that event occurs.

```
<button onClick="fn()"> Call `fn();` </button>
```

```
function fn(){
    console.log('that button was pressed');
}
```

There are many such events. One that you may be using also is `onScroll`, which fires when a page is scrolled. It's a very sensitive event and it fires for the smallest of fluctuations in scroll positions. This may be the reason your form is being posted many times at once.

---

> So I can just stick a function `example()` into my routing/server file, and then use `<button onClick="example()">Call 'example()';</button>` and then code `example()` to `db.collection.find().limit(10)` to make it possible to push database requests around?

No, you're mixing client-side and server-side code.

HTML elements, like `<button>`, and JavaScript associated with them, like `onClick` events, all reside on client-side, on the Browser.

You server-side code, NodeJS, can only be interacted with or respond to client through HTTP requests, like `GET /`, `POST /form`.

What you need is probably AJAX, which is basically using client-side JavaScript to make and handle result of above mentioned requests made to the server.

Comment: So I can just stick a function example() into my routing/server file, and then use <button onClick="example()">Call 'example()';</button>, and then code example() to db.collection.find().limit(10) to make it possible to push database requests around?